# How to display UMTS signal strength?

Tags: networking, network-manager, wireless, usb

Using a random UMTS USB stick (Huwei 160 or something like this) works an current Ubuntu pretty much out of the box and the setup via network manager (nm-applet) is convenient.

But it does not display the current signal strength or modes of operation (which speed-mode is used etc.).

What are useful tools to display/monitor such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version **0.8.1** of **network-manager** is already all-inclusive (http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/ReleaseProcess).

Otherwise you can use **umtsmon** (http://umtsmon.sourceforge.net/)

or **vodafoneMobileConnect** (https://forge.betavine.net/projects/vodafonemobilec/)

or **bcm** (https://forge.betavine.net/projects/bcm/)

if you have a too old version of ubuntu that does not allow you to update network-manager.

Comment: What does "all-inclusive" mean? I can't find any info about connection mode in network manager (it shows the signal strength in the icon).

Answer (score 3):

`modem-manager-gui` gives that info on "info" tab:

[image: modem-manager 3g connection info]

In distros other than Ubuntu, the package name can be `modem-manager`.

Comment: on ubuntu 16.04 modemmanager is already installed. it should be modem-manager-gui

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing much that I am aware of that does this. I have written my own scripts that monitor the second usb serial connection and query for signal strength.

Send a AT+CSQ and you will receive:

+CSQ: n

n is in the range 1 - 31, to convert this to dBm subtract 111

This is detailed in the GSM / 3GPP spec  http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/html-info/27007.htm

Comment: Ok, this is a start. What is the most convenient way to send such control sequences from a script?

Answer (score 0):

This screenlet works for me-
[WirelessScreenlet](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/WirelessScreenlet?content=71861/)

You need to install screenlets first from the software center.

Comment: Hm, does it really supports UMTS? This page does not mention UMTS.